# App force closes after splash screen on testing

Tags: java, android, xml

```
package com.ave;

import com.ave.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class Menu extends Activity{
ImageButton select;    
int isClicked = 0;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                select = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.select);
        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if (isClicked == 0){
                        select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_pressed);
                        isClicked = 1;
                     }
                     else{
                        select.setImageResource(R.drawable.select);
                        isClicked = 0;
                     }
                }});
        }

        ImageButton audio;    
        int isClicked1 = 0;{

        audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio);
        audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                     if (isClicked1 == 0){
                        audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                        isClicked1 = 1;
                     }
                     else{
                        audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                        isClicked1 = 0;
                     }
                 }
           });
         }
      }
```

============LogCat=================

```
E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ave/com.ave.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1693)
E AndroidRuntime:     at com.ave.Menu.(Menu.java:41)
E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1610)
E AndroidRuntime: ... 11 more
```

I have no errors within xml or class and everything is referenced properly but when i try to test the app through AVD or my phone it force stops after the splash screen. And produces what you see in the LogCat. Again no errors in the xml or classes and everything is referenced. So what am i doing wrong? Or what needs to be added. It all stopped working after adding the second imageButton method, but if i remove it. It works fine.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/droid_background">
    <TextView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <ImageButton 
android:src="@drawable/select"
android:id="@+id/select"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <ImageButton
android:src="@drawable/audio"
android:id="@+id/audio"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:background="@null"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>'
```

Comment: What's throwing the error is `findViewById(R.id.audio)`. Post your `main.xml`.

Comment: You have two ImageButtons with the same id.

Comment: hah i think that go thrown in there while trying to fix something hold on let me see if this works.

Comment: Ok i removed the 2nd audio ImageButton, but to no aveil. It force closes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run "Clean Up" to the project? Sometimes XML layouts needs to be regenerated in order app to work as expected.

Comment: It says that the problem is on line 41.
That is `audio = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.audio);` right?
If so: it can't find `R.id.audio`...

Comment: ok hm eclipse isn't flagging it or marking it at all. No errors for either menu which would what its talking about, or the main.xml.

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste the XML layout for the Menu Activity?

Comment: You have prematurelly ended onCreate() method. On line 35 you have `}}` which messes up the things. Remove one of them and fix other braces as appropriate.

Comment: You should be just before the end of the method.

Comment: this is getting me somewhere! But not out of the woods yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your Activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: yes, I added the second imageButton method, and everything went sour from there. if i remove it. It all works fine. I guess i should have mentioned that in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ImageButtons with the id audio. Try renaming one.